# Is there a term or phrase for a person with two singing voice (male - female singing voice)?

Tags: phrase-requests

There are some people who have distinct voices when they sing, currently when I Google it there are only phrases like "... with two voices ..." Is there a word for a person who have that ability?

Edit:
Thank you Katherine Lockwood, that was something new and interesting for me actually, but currently the word I'm looking for is the counter-tenor.

Comment: Typically, men and women have different vocal ranges. You might want to google that.

Comment: Are you asking about people singing with two voices *at the same time,* or are you talking about people who can do different singing voices at different times, or who have a singing voice that is very different from their speaking voice?

Comment: Are you referring to 'falsetto'?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To be more precise with regard to the OP, a male opera singer who sings in a faux-female voice is termed a *countertenor*.

"A countertenor is a type of classical male singing voice whose vocal range is that of the female contralto or mezzo-soprano...Countertenors are often [male] baritones or tenors at core, but rarely use this vocal range in performance". (Wikipedia)

Comment: We should also mention a falsetto voice which does not form part of mainstream opera but exists for those who wish to adopt such a voice in conversation or as a way of singing, etc.

Answer (score 10):

You may be thinking of a specialized kind of singing in which a singer shapes his/her vocal tract to amplify [overtones or harmonics](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/harmonic) (Merriam-Webster) of the [fundamental frequency](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/funhar.html) (Georgia State University Physics & Astronomy). This type of singing is often called "throat singing" or "overtone singing." The resulting sound is a lower pitched "drone" that does not change much, along with higher-pitched sounds that are manipulated to make tunes.

Encyclopedia Brittanica Online has a general overview of [Throat Singing](https://www.britannica.com/art/throat-singing). There are various styles of overtone singing. [Alex Glenfield's YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7zZainT9v6Q) demonstrates seven of them but does not describe them in terms of how they are produced. [Anna-Maria Hefele has a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UHTF1-IhuC0) that includes some spectrograms and explanations. There are many other videos on YouTube of various people--men and women--doing harmonic/overtone/throat singing.

As for your phrase-request, I would say the phrase in English would be "throat singer."

I could be way off base here--you may be looking for something as simple as a man who can use a falsetto voice--but it seems from your phrase "two voices" that you are looking for throat-singing.

Answer (score 0):

I heard of a term called “ Ryouseirui” before. It is a Japanese term to describe people who are able to sing in both typically male and female ranges. It appears in English usage.

> [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ryouseirui)
>
> Ryouseirui (両声類) literally translates to "both vocal species", and is a Japanese term to describe people who are able to sing two genders (a high voice and a low voice). An English term of somewhat similar meaning is "androgynous."

The word androgynous is more general and is not only applied to singing.

> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/androgynous)
>
> If you describe someone as androgynous, you mean that they are not distinctly masculine or feminine in appearance or in behaviour.

Comment: This doesn't look like an English word.

Answer (score 0):

You might be referring to two [registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocal_register) of a singer's voice, such as their usual voice and their [falsetto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsetto) voice.